# PHP file not being run

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that I'm trying to run. However, my web browsers act like it doesn't exist.
For example, 
Firefox tries to open the PHP file
Chrome says This webpage is not available. Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.
Internet Explorer says  Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

I'm trying to access this php file through a form submission ie action="login.php"
I've also tried accessing this file by localhost/login.php and I get the same results.

I know php is configured properly because all my other php files run fine just this one is giving me problems. For example, localhost/home.php works

btw, I do not have this problem when I tried to load the php file (it works properly) on another computer I have so I know the php file compiles properly.

Anyone have any ideas? I tried deleting all my caches (Firefox, IE, Chrome, Twig) but nothing works.

Thanks

edit: here are the php files i'm talking about
login.php

```
    function generate_salt($username) 
    {  
        // Create a SHA1 hash  
        $salt = sha1('~'.$username.'~'.microtime(TRUE).'~');  

        // Limit to random 10 characters in the hash  
        $salt = substr($salt, rand(0,30), 10);  

        return $salt;  
    }

    function hash_password($password, $salt) 
    {  
        return sha1('~'.$password.'~'.$salt.'~');  
    }  

    function valid_password($password, $hash, $salt) 
    {  
        return hash_password($password, $salt) == $hash;  
    }
    $loginStatus = false;

    //echo $_POST['username'] . " ";
    //echo $_POST['password'] . "\n";

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $db = new dbHelper(); 


    $user = $db->getUser($username);


    if(!$user)
    {
        $loginStatus = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $loginStatus = valid_password($password, $user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
    }

    if($loginStatus)
    {
        $db->createSession($user);
    }

    if($loginStatus)
    {
        echo "Login Successful";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0;URL=index.php"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0;URL=index.php#ui-tabs-3"/>';
    }
    //echo json_encode($loginStatus);
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
    //require_once './library.php';
    require_once './twigLoader.php';
    require_once './loginStatus.php';

    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('home.html');

    $nameArr = array("hi", "bye");

    echo $template->render(array('loginStatus' => $loginStatus,
                                'nameArr' => $nameArr));
?>
```

Comment: can you post the file contents?

Comment: sure i'll pastie them

login.php http://pastie.org/1027606
home.php http://pastie.org/1027607

Comment: btw the only two differences between the computers is one uses straight up apache, php, and mysql and the other uses wamp - wamp doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check Apache's error_log or the PHP log file, if any. Most likely there's an early error in the script. You can also try activating the [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [`display_startup_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) options in your php.ini (I'm assuming this is a development installation).

Comment: nothing related to php in my apache logs and my php log file is empty
how is there an error in the script if it runs fine on another computer? those are already active in my php.ini

Comment: @use You could have a different PHP configuration in the two computers (e.g. one module could not be loaded). Anyway, you don't give enough information to resolve this problem. Perhaps one your includes kills the script prematurely with `die` or `exit`. It's impossible to tell. Try using xdebug to step through your script.

Comment: i have no idea either cause i get no error output but its weird because my script runs successfully on my other computer

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of xampp.